# IE absolute table position leaves whitespace

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, position

I'm currently fighting with IE. Before I get some rants about tables I know "dont use them", but I didn't write this, I'm just debugging it. I'd like to know if there is some hack to get the table spacing out of the flow on IE, when I absolute position a table. I included some style to help see the issue better. There is a bar of white space that doesn't belong to anything. This works great on FF and Chrome, IE just breaks the flow on this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .button{
                float:left;
                Background:#0F0;
            }

            #testCont{
                Background:#F00;
            }

            #testUnder{
                Clear:both;
                Background:#00F;
                Color:#FFF;
            }

            .tablePop{
                position: absolute;
                top:60px;
                left:60px;
                Background:#CACACA;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div  id="testCont">
            <div class="button">
                Button1
            </div>
            <div class="button">
                Button2
            </div>
            <div class="button">
                Button3
            </div>
            <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 class="tablePop">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Row 1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Row 2
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Row 3
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div  id="testUnder">
            Hello World
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a comment: there's nothing wrong with using tables for tabular data. It's just that you're not supposed to use them for layouts.

Comment: True, but I don't think a popup menu counts as tabular data.

Comment: just a silly thought.. But does it help when you add tbody tags? IE is a bit weird with those.

Comment: Just added them. Good idea but didn't do a dang thing. The crappy thing is this white space isn't in the layout according to the debug tools. I can't select it.

Comment: just a test. Put a `div` containing the three buttons and make it `overflow:auto` just to see if anything changes

Comment: What version of IE are you using? Almost sounds like the double-margin bug ;)

Comment: IE10 renders the same as Chrome. You'll have to tell us what version you're testing in.

Comment: Im testing in IE8 and IE9. I tried the overflow:auto. Didn't effect how IE rendered anything, It did change how FF and Chrome did though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your page in standards mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
```

You can test this out quickly by pressing F12 and switching the document mode to standards.

Alternatively, you could also use `display:inline` instead of `float:left` for `.button`.

Comment: While this works and I'll check it, this will break so much javascript and other IE hacks on our site I can't use it.

Comment: @busbina *Don't use hacks* ;)

Comment: Were using Dojo and there are so many dojo.ifIE id have to go through and refactor all of it.